# Getting forced close when selecting attachment on QGIS 3.2.1?

Tags: qgis-3

I added a new column, labelled it "pics" then I go to properties, layer form, change widget type of "pics" to attachment and set default path to the folder location of my images. Now when I go to attributes and click the 3 dots(...) it goes to the location of the folder then it forced close the QGIS application.

Why am I getting forced close?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in QGIS. I think this is the sort of a bug in 3-rd version.
As an alternative You can hide that "..." button in attachment settings and then put file path manually.